# Decrypt to memory for editing

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, memory, windows-10

I am looking for a secure way to edit sensitive text data, using Git and Vim in the process.

An ideal solution would be:

1. clone the encrypted git repository into memory;
2. decrypt into memory;
3. do the editing, in-memory;
4. encrypt, in-memory;
5. push back to the repository;
6. remove from memory.

How can this setup be realized with the key requirement that no files ever touch persistent storage?

In my case, I'm using Windows 10, but I'm also interested how one would approach this on Linux.

**Update.**

[RAMDisk](http://www.radeonramdisk.com/software_downloads.php) Solved the in-memory part of the problem.

I'm currently looking into preventing the data from getting on disk, like @StevenUllrich mentioned in the comments, by using an encrypted swap- or page file.

Comment: How about simply using a RAM disk for this? It is kept in memory only and once you remove the disk its gone.  The goal itself should probably also be achievable with a encrypted disk in a file which you can remove after use. Of course, you need to make sure that no temporary files from editing ever gets saved to the real disk. *"Is there an implementation of a tool that, ..."* - product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's exactly what I need, for step 3 and 6. :) I ended up using [RAMDisk](http://www.radeonramdisk.com/software_downloads.php). I'm currently looking into steps 2 and 4; I'm also considering a certain 2FA construction.

Comment: At least on Linux you can also use full disk encryption with RAM disks. Of course, the decrypted content will end up in the RAM anyway since otherwise the editor could not work with it so it is questionable if encrypting the RAM disk is useful. But you should use an encrypted swap or page file since otherwise the content might end up on disk in clear anyway.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich My intention is to decrypt the *files* in the RAM, not the RAM disk itself. The purpose of encryption will be to secure the data on the git repository in the cloud. I'm currently looking into ways to, in some way, use the 2FA app on my phone to unlock encryption of the files via the command line.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Could you elaborate on how use of an encrypted swap or page file is warranted for the content to stay off disk?

Comment: How to encrypt swap or page file can be easily found by searching for [encrypted swap linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=encrypted+swap+linux) or  [encrypted page file windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=encrypted+page+file+windows). On why it is needed: if more RAM is needed than actually available disk backed paging/swapping is done to make room in the RAM.

Comment: Even if you aren't completely out of memory, you will start swapping a bit. The default threshold for Linux is rather crazy (very aggressive swappiness).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich On using an encrypted file on disk which is removed afterwards, when *removing/deleting* something from disk it isn't strictly *gone*. When using RAM, however, this *can* be guaranteed.

Comment: @MusséRedi: It is true that an encrypted but locally stored disk would not be really gone immediately when you remove it. But since it was encrypted the content is not accessible as soon as the encryption key is no longer known which essentially makes the content not accessible any more even if the disk itself would still be there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich True, the file will still be encrypted, indeed. However, without 2FA, I will be relying merely on my passphrase, since the private key can be compromised on this system; for me to use it, I will have to transfer the private key to the disk. The passphrase can then be retrieved by brute-force, if I'm not mistaken. With RAM, we don't have this worry. Please do correct me, if I'm not making sense. :)

Comment: @MusséRedi: proper full disk encryption will not use the passphrase for encryption but derive a key from the passphrase using some explicitly slow KDF. Thus, unless your passphrase is weak brute forcing to get the correct encryption key will take forever.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Actually, that's what I meant; the encryption key (derived from the passphrase) will need to be copied to the filesystem, at some point, for the decryption tool to have access to it, right? At which point it can become compromised in a later stage.

Comment: @MusséRedi: when accessing an encrypted volume you usually enter the passphrase which gets used to created the encryption key which then gets kept in memory to decrypt the content. While it might be that there is some (broken) solution which saves the key to disk and invokes another tool with it there is no need to actually do so and no proper solution would do this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Okay, so it's just a matter of copy pasting the strong passphrase into the decryption tool, keeping in mind not the to the passphrase on disk, but acquiring it via any other possible channel; web-browser or external storage (flash drive, etc. )?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77085/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-musse-redi).